# Как можно сделать чтобы программа на go сама открывала порты и можно было к ней подключиться через интернет, а не по локалке

Tags: golang, port

Как можно сделать чтобы программа на go сама открывала порты и можно было к ней подключиться через интернет, а не по локалке. Можно ли как-то открыть порты программно? Вот когда устанавливаешь какой-нибудь мессенджер, он же не просит лезть в роутер и открывать порты, он просто работает. Как это реализовать?
Тут-то конечно сервер, и его насколько я понимаю надо на отдельную машину и на ней открывать порты, но есть же p2p приложения без проброса портов в роутере, которые прекрасно работают.
Слышал про Upnp - подойдет здесь? Как это можно реализовать в golang?

Answer (score 0):

Вы совершенно верно обратили внимание на *проброс портов* (легко гуглится).

Для реализации этого наверное проще всего использовать сторонние системные средства (скрипты).

Что-то вроде [вот такого](https://www.opennet.ru/base/net/nat_redirect.txt.html) скрипта в linux.

А для его запуска использовать пакет [exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) из golang.